# Type checking in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, typechecking

I have `public IList<ListingHistoryItem> History { get; set; }` in one of my pages' view models. The `ListingHistoryItem` is an abstract class and has two subclasses `BidDto` and `CommentDto`. The reason why I'm doing it this way is because, the listing has some sort of a news feed which displays any bids or comments on the listing.

So anyway, what I'm trying to do is, in my view check the concrete type of the History element and then display it accordingly. Here's how I'm trying to do it:

```
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.History.Count; i++)
    {
        var feed = Model.History[i];

        if (feed.GetType().FullName.Equals(Sharwe.MVC.Models.BidDto))
```

But this last line gives the following exception:

> Sharwe.MVC.Models.BidDto' is a 'type',
>   which is not valid in the given
>   context

So how am I supposed to check for the type? Or am I doing it totally wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try like this:

```
if (feed is Sharwe.MVC.Models.BidDto)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I did not know the `is` keyword could be used inside Razor views. Thanks for the hint. :)